# LSI MegaRaid Controller - Switched OS's

Tags: linux, raid, kubuntu

I originally installed the MegaRaid Controller on Windows. I switched to Kubuntu and now I'm having great difficulties getting the raid setup recognized.

I don't really need the raid (Just the controller since the cards are SAS).

Additionally, if I use `megasasctl`, I get the return:

```
No LSI MegaRAID SAS cards found. You may try megactl instead.
```

And the same thing if I use `megactl`.

I tried following several tutorials online, which use the tool directly from Avagotech/LSI, without any luck getting it installed.

At this point I really don't care about the raid, I just need the disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use MegaCli utility for RAID controllers on Linux. You can get it from LSI site. I don't know what RAID controller model you have and can this utility see it.